# C++ Input Timer

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

So, I am making a game, and I need input function  to have deadline, and I want that time to be displayed in one of the console corners.
I have timer running on separate thread, but I do not know how to interupt input function when it finishes.
**Also, as I mentioned I want to show user how much time he has left, lets say to write varibale TimeLeft on end of the first line,but keep all other lines intact.**
Any help would be appriciated.
Working in C++, Windows platform, console app

Comment: I regret to inform you that your apparent belief that every operating system in the world handles input in exactly the same way is wrong. The correct answer depends not only on the operating system, but also on the input environment (i.e. console input, and X applications, on Linux). Therefore, your question does not have an answer.

Comment: you're right. I forgot to mention its Working in C++, Windows platform, console app.